# Align elements/item vertically center in CSS Display Flex (flex - direction : column)

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRy79.png)I'm new to React and trying a POC with flex.
my page have a main div (main_div) with flex direction column, now trying to aling the items vertically in center for its child (months_div_inline and month_div) but it is not working with "align-content" or "justify-content". can any one help me with this thanks in advance.

CheckPOC.js

```
import React from "react";
import './check.css';
class CheckPOC extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        };
    }

    render(){
        const {size} = this.props;      
        return(
            <>
                <div 
                    className="main_div"
                    style={{width:size, height:size}}>
                    <div className="header_div">
                        <div className="months_div_inline month_name">{"Months"}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="month_div">check</div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
};

export default CheckPOC;
```

check.css

```
.main_div {
    border:2px ridge grey;
    border-radius: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;

}

.header_div {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    /* display: inline; */
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.month_name {
    flex: 5;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}


.month_div {
    flex: 7;
    /* background-color:darkgray; */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
    /* align-items: center; */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using `justify-content: center`
In your `.main_div` class should fix your issue.

When using `display: flex;` `flex-direction: column;`, the cross axis and main axis switch from when using the default `flex-direction: row;`.

*For flex-direction: row; (the default):*

**justify-content controls horizontal alignment.**

**align-items and align-content control vertical alignment.**

*For flex-direction: column;*

**justify-content controls vertical alignment.**

**align-items and align-content control horizontal alignment.**

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks for the suggestion i have tried it with justify-content and justify-items both but it didn’t work. Also I tried removing the margin: 0px that is added in .header_div class css but no difference.

Comment: Found the solution, along with the align-content and justify-content I have to apply the display= flex for the month_div and it will align my text/child in the center